# Cordova url's and image src has 'unsafe' infront of url in Windows

Tags: angularjs, cordova, windows-10

I'm working on a Cordova application with Angular and I'm struggeling on something for Windows.

I'm trying something like this:

```
<img ng-src="{{dataDirectory + buildingPhoto.FilenamePhoto}}" class="full-width">
```

**dataDirectory** = "ms-appdata:///local"
**buildingPhoto.FilenamePhoto** = "VOL-00122kaftfoto_thumb.png"

But this only results in a broken image with this code:

```
<img class="full-width" src="unsafe:ms-appdata:///local/VOL-00122kaftfoto_thumb.png" ng-src="ms-appdata:///local/VOL-00122kaftfoto_thumb.png">
```

I figured the `unsafe` means the prefix is seen as insecure and it needs to be whitelisted, thus I added this in my `app.js`:

```
.config(['$compileProvider', function($compileProvider) {

    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|ghttps?|ms-appx|ms-appdata|x-wmapp0):/);
    $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|file|ms-appx|ms-appdata|x-wmapp0):|data:image\//);
}])
```

I also added this meta tag inside my index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="ms-appdata *; default-src *; img-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />
```

**But it's not working, so I'm kinda stuck here and hope somebody can push me in the right direction.**

Comment: `$compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|file|ms-appx-web):/);` worked for me, so maybe try to add `ms-appx-web`...

Comment: Tried your line, but didn't seem to work. I don't get it though, because I also tried adding |ms-appdata to the regex and the regex appears correct. I'm clueless for this.

Comment: Hmm what windows version are you compiling for? You could add the correspondig tag...

Comment: Windows 10 x64. How would I add the corresponding tag?

Comment: I added the windows-10 tag, let's hope my edit will be approved ;)

Comment: Anyway are you able to make a simpler example work? Like `ng-src="path\to\any\image"`

Comment: @Phonolog and where do I add this tag? And I tried adding an image that's located in my image folder on my computer. I don't get the 'unsafe' tag in front of it, but the image doesn't show either. But I don't think the image not showing is the issue, I need to get rid of the 'unsafe' bit

Comment: Hmm I'm pretty out of ideas here, maybe the bounty helps...

Comment: @Phonolog what would in your opinion be the most logic approach to whitelist an image protocol?

Comment: Have you tried moving `ms-appdata` inside default-src? `"default-src 'self' data: gap: ms-appdata: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *"`?

Comment: Tried that meta but line ended up looking like this: `<img class="full-width" src="unsafe:ms-appdata:///local/VOL-00122kaftfoto_thumb.png" ng-src="ms-appdata:///local/VOL-00122kaftfoto_thumb.png">`
Anything in the app.js you would do with the config?

Comment: @Phonolog After spending some time on this, i noticed 'local' is not added in the whitelisting. How about adding local in the whitelist and try once as mentioned in the link - https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4511 Please keep me posted

Comment: @JorisDecraecker Try out the comment above and let me know

Comment: @Gandhi thanks for helping out. Unfortunately that didnt work either. Here is the line I added: `$compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|file|content|blob|ms-appx|ms-appdata|x-wmapp0|unsafe|local):|data:image\//);`

Comment: @JorisDecraecker Oh i m sorry about that. Could you try out this in your config code:  app.config(function ($compileProvider) {
  var whitelist = $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist();
  whitelist = new RegExp(whitelist.source.replace(/(ftp)/, '$1|ms-appdata'));
  $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(whitelist);
});

Comment: Bleh also didn't work. What exactly does the `whitelist = new RegExp(whitelist.source.replace(/(ftp)/, '$1|ms-appdata'));` do?

Comment: @JorisDecraecker It jus adds ms-appdata to the existing whitelist source. Came across one more post who got it working. Check out - https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/jpeg-images-dont-render-because-of-unsafe-prefix-while-png-images-show-fine/49572

Comment: @JorisDecraecker Sorry about giving probable answers as i dont have the infrastructure to test this issue. I only deal with iOS and android devices. Please bare with me

Comment: @Gandhi @Phonolog you were both right from the start. All of your solutions worked. The issue here (and I need to make sure I don't start swearing) was that the $compileProvider I made was in `app.js`, but at the same time, there was another $compileProvider in `router.js`. So basically my actions got canceled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for days I finally found the solution to my problem.
Everything I was doing was correct. The only problem was that I was applying all of this in my app.js, while in my router.js everything got overridden by different code.

Lesson: always check if the angular app has configurations in other files before applying a patch

Comment: There is one more lesson learnt from this question. Always ensure to post the complete code in questions to arrest all the corner case scenarios. That too for bounty quesions, it is very much necessary as it gets lot of attention. Anyways glad that you cracked it. Cheers

Answer (score 6):

Image src whitelisting using the following code fixes the issue:

```
$compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|file|content|blob‌​|ms-appx|ms-appdata|x-wmapp0|unsafe|local):|data:image\//);
```

**Also ensure that $compileProvider is not getting overridden anywhere else after the initial setting in app.js** which actually resulted in the issue for Joris.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best solution.

```
myApp.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|file|chrome-extension|ms-appx-web|ms-appx):|data:image\//);
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|chrome-extension|ms-appx-web|ms-appx):/);
}]);
```